# SQL Server: Email to operator in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

Is it possible to send an email to an email operator in a stored procedure? I need to generate an HTML email. I can use `sp_notify_operator`, but that doesn't seem to have any option to set `body_format` to HTML and `sp_send_dbmail` doesn't seem to have a way to email an operator. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the email address from `msdb.dbo.sysoperators`

then use `sp_send_dbmail` to send to that email address